# Is there a way to display a 16:9 web page stretched over more than 3 screens with correct text aspect ratio and without noticeable pixelation?

Tags: css, fonts, css-transforms

**Background**

On commercial TVs, there's a mode called Video Wall mode, where you can stretch a single desktop across multiple screens. Let's say I'm working with 4 screens, I'm trying to make a web page that appears like it's not stretched, which means on a normal single screen showing one desktop it will look like it's been compressed 4 times.

I've currently got a partial solution by creating a 4 desktop wide page, then using CSS trasform to scale the page by 1/4 horizontally.

Although images are blurry, that could be mitigated by excluding transformation on elements with images.

**The issue**

When the scaling transform is done, the fonts are pixelated as if they went through a bad (low quality) jpeg compression.

Below is my current code sample.

```css
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: min-content;
    animation: fadein 3s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

.screen {
    display: grid;
    grid: 50% auto / 50% auto;
}
.main {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
}
.dynamic {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.list {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.dynamic .item {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 49.8%;
}

.dynamic .item > div {
    position: relative;
    transform-origin: left;
}
.dynamic .item .name {
    display: block;
}
.dynamic .item .header > * {
    display: inline-flex;
}
.dynamic .item .values > * {
    display: inline-flex;
}



@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    body {
        font-size: 4vh;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    .screen {
        width: calc(8000vh/(9*5));
        height: 100vh;
    }
    .dynamic .text { font-size: 2vh }
    .dynamic .name > * { font-size: 4vh }
    .list { font-size: 2vh }
    .list .title { font-size: 4vh }
}

@media (aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    body {
        flex-direction: row;
        width: calc(8000vh/9);
        height: 100vh;
        transform: scaleX(.25);
        transform-origin: top left;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="screen">
        <div class="list">
            <div class="section">
                <div class="title text">Subsection 1</div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="text">Text 1</div>
                    <div class="text">Text 2</div>
                    <div class="text">Text 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <div class="title text">Subsection 2</div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="text">Text 1</div>
                    <div class="text">Text 2</div>
                    <div class="text">Text 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main"></div>
        <div class="dynamic">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="name"><span class="text">Subsection 1</span></div>
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="text"><span>Header 1</span></div>
                    <div class="text"><span>Header 2</span></div>
                    <div class="text"><span>Header 3</span></div>
                    <div class="text"><span>Header 4</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="values">
                    <div class="text"><span>Text 1</span></div>
                    <div class="text"><span>Text 2</span></div>
                    <div class="text"><span>Text 3</span></div>
                    <div class="text"><span>Text 4</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="name"><span class="text">Subsection 2</span></div>
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="text"><span>Header 1</span></div>
                    <div class="text"><span>Header 2</span></div>
                    <div class="text"><span>Header 3</span></div>
                    <div class="text"><span>Header 4</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="values">
                    <div class="text"><span>Text 1</span></div>
                    <div class="text"><span>Text 2</span></div>
                    <div class="text"><span>Text 3</span></div>
                    <div class="text"><span>Text 4</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What is causing this, and is there a way to work around it, using HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you had a website that was made with only mobile in mind, and you wanted to make it good to go for desktop, you wouldn't use transform scale, right? Simply don't use transform for that. Use media-queries and adjust the actual size of the elements accordingly. Using scale like that will mess with the pixel values and cause this blurry effect.

It doesn't matter how big or small the media you're working with is, the principles of responsive design work the same. Use relative units instead of absolute ones and it's not that hard.

If you use `rem` units for font-sizes, margins and paddings and etc, and unitless line-heights, they are relative to the root font-size (which is normally 16px by default), so by modifying the font-size on the `html` element, they will all scale in proportion. For general layout structure, you can use percentages, or even better, use [CSS Grid and `fr` units](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Images will require a bit more work, as you should provably use different images for different sizes, but for everything else, this does it.

A demonstration:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 7.5rem max-content 1fr;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
}

.header__title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 2.25;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar {
  display:       flex;
  background:    lightblue;
  border-top:    0.125rem solid;
  border-bottom: 0.125rem solid;
}

.navbar__item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.content {
  background: silver;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.content__title {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 2.25;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  
  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="header__title">Title</h1>
  </header>
  
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
  </nav>
    
  <article class="content">
    <h2 class="content__title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate at omnis hic, maxime ab iure facilis. Dolore alias veniam nisi doloribus at corrupti sapiente ipsam quo voluptates? Excepturi, mollitia qui!</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate at omnis hic, maxime ab iure facilis. Dolore alias veniam nisi doloribus at corrupti sapiente ipsam quo voluptates? Excepturi, mollitia qui!</p>
  </article>
</main>
```

Simple enough, right? The conversion to `rem` is basically the pixel value divided by 16 (the default root font-size). Now adding just a single line, we can scale everything:

```css
html { font-size: 32px; } /* added just that, doubling the scale (16*2 = 32) */

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 7.5rem max-content 1fr;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
}

.header__title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 2.25;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar {
  display:       flex;
  background:    lightblue;
  border-top:    0.125rem solid;
  border-bottom: 0.125rem solid;
}

.navbar__item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.content {
  background: silver;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.content__title {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 2.25;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  
  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="header__title">Title</h1>
  </header>
  
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar__item">item</a>
  </nav>
    
  <article class="content">
    <h2 class="content__title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate at omnis hic, maxime ab iure facilis. Dolore alias veniam nisi doloribus at corrupti sapiente ipsam quo voluptates? Excepturi, mollitia qui!</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate at omnis hic, maxime ab iure facilis. Dolore alias veniam nisi doloribus at corrupti sapiente ipsam quo voluptates? Excepturi, mollitia qui!</p>
  </article>
</main>
```

---

**Edit**: Okay, I see it now - after the discussion on the comments. If your hardware is the one doing the scaling, and not the browser, I believe you are out of luck. But it should be possible to configure your monitors to extend one another horizontally instead, which would make it a proper 7680x1080 canvas that you could detect with a media-query for a 64:9 aspect ratio. Most OS will have that option (excluding things like windows starter). Ubuntu is a free option that have it out of the box, for example. I just assumed that's what you had, since it's usually the simplest way to go.

Comment: I think my case might be a bit unique, because of what the example is doing with the 4 screens - this is not a 7680x1080 browser window/display output stretched over a 4 x 16:9 screen, this is a 1920x1080 browser window/display output stretched over a 4 x 16:9 screen - the way you've described would make the fonts look streched horizontally 500%.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. I'm not stretching anything, in any direction, so that's impossible.

Comment: There's a physical portion to this question - this page is being displayed on more than one screen horizontally that is showing one 16:9 desktop over all the screens. So yes, the content isn't stretched if seen on a normal monitor. The part that will stretch is the physical setup of the question in hand.

Comment: **edit**: moved the comment to the answer, as it would help someone looking for it better there than hidden here in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, that does sound like it would work depending on the graphics card (eyefinity) and/or monitor support. I did find another solution that is a little 
less optimal and easier, but since your answer should work as well, marking it as answer!

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason to be related to OS anti-aliasing - since I believe you're not supposed to be able to change or force anti-aliasing on the fonts through the browser.

Since I'm on Windows, enabling ClearType smoothed out the text enough to be legible.

Comment: There was a [font-smooth CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth) in the early drafts of the CSS3 specs that would be used to control anti-aliasing, but it has been removed and never implemented. Firefox and webkit both have a similar property, but only for OS X/macOS, that are mainly used just to make it more consistent with other systems that do not render text using sub-pixel anti-aliasing, like so (at the `html` element): `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`